# If and else statement using diff -q

Tags: shell-script, test

So I'm trying to write an if else statement which involves the use of `diff -q`. 
So, let's say I have two files `hi.txt` and `hello.txt` and I store them into variables called hi and hello respectively. I have this piece of code

```
if [ diff -q $hi $hello ]; then
  echo "these files are the same"
else 
  echo "these files are not the same"
fi
```

No matter what `hi.txt` and `hello.txt` contain, even if they have exactly the same content. I get an error saying

```
./(name of script) line (line with [diff -q hi hello]) [: too many arguments.
```

What part of my syntax is wrong?

Answer (score 8):

1. You don't put diff in brackets
2. The Syntax to use variable is `$hi`

so the resulting script is:

```
if diff -q $hi $hello; then
echo "these files are the same"
else
echo "these files are not the same"
fi
```

Comment: if the answer works for you, don't just say thanks - accept it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow